# SSL on AWS S3, Deployed on Heroku

Tags: heroku, amazon-s3

I have a Django app deployed on Heroku with AWS S3 handling images. The S3 bucket name contains a "-" and no ".".

After using SSL for my domain (and having done the necessary configuration on Heroku), I run into issues uploading images to AWS S3 via the SSL domain.

Chrome's error: ERR_CONNECTION_RESET
Firefox error: The page you are trying to view cannot be shown because the authenticity of the received data could not be verified.

What is the problem? Thanks much.